# Keeping the text color when the button is clicked

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have 3 buttons of type `system`. Every button has a color: red, green, blue.

All the buttons belong to a custom class.

Inside that class I have this method:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
  [super setHighlighted:highlighted];

  self.backgroundColor = highlighted ? darkColor : normalColor;

}
```

When this runs, the button changes from its normal color to a dark color. So far so good, but while the button is highlighted the text color changes from white (the normal color) to a gray one.

Because I am already doing a dramatic change in color, I don't want the text to change from white.

I have tried to modify the awakeFromNib to set the text to white for both states normal/highlight, to force the text to remain white, without change. Buttons. Reverses on highlight is off, shows touch on highlight is off.

How do I do that?

---

Note: xcode is so buggy that setting the color for the highlight state does not work for the white color. It keeps "default" as color. I have then set the color of the text highlight state just to see. No change. Text continues to change to gray when tapped.

Comment: you can set from storyboard , select button , select state and change tint color

Comment: have you try that? Xcode is so buggy that this does not work. Try to set the color for other states. It will stay "default". It will not set. I am using the avenir font.

Comment: what type of text you have in button if it is attributed text then it will not work

Comment: you need to setAttributedTitle

Comment: I did that too. Did not work either. I think I may be facing a corruption in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `-setTitleColor:forState:`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitleColor:forState:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `UIButton` `title color` also , Same as `BackGroundColor` .

It working for me ,Try this or fell free.

Comment: I checked that i was done by using tint color on the button.

When i free i try like this , If i got any thing , i will tell you.

Comment: sorry, not working for tint also. Thanks anyway. I have added more info.